# PHP cannot open ghostscript generated files

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I have a small php function which uses ghostscript to take a multipage pdf and convert it to multiple pngs. This part of the script works perefctly i can run it and check the images folder and they are all there.

The next part of the script resizes the pngs produced by ghostcript. However any attempt to make use of these pngs in php results in "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Moreover if copy one of the generated pngs to another folder or even the same folder it will become readable. This leads me to believe the ghostscript generated images might have the incorrect permissions. But when i run my script to check for permissions and if the file exists. both return false.

Here is the conversion script:

```
    <?php
 //Upload pdf convert to pngs in the folder jpgs/originals
$uploaddir = 'uploadtemp/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
echo "<p>";
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

    exec('bin\gswin32c.exe -o jpgs\originals\%3d.png -sDEVICE=png16m -r150 uploadtemp\input.pdf');
    unlink('uploadtemp\input.pdf');
    header('Location: main.php');
    } else {
    echo "Upload failed";
}       
?>
```

Here is the script which tries to call the now generated pngs:

```
 <?php
$filename = "jpgs/originals/1.png";

    if (is_writable($filename)) {
        echo 'The file is writable';
    } else {
        echo 'The file is not writable';
    }

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "The file $filename exists";
    } else {
        echo "The file $filename does not exist";
?>
```

Both if statements return false even though i can see the files generated in the folder

Comment: Check that your script is looking in the folder that you think it's looking in (relative filepaths aren't so smart when the working directory might be different); check file permissions, just because you have permission to see the folder contents, doesn't mean that PHP has

Comment: @MarkBaker I know its looking in the right folder because if paste in file from elsewhere and simply change the filename it recognizes the file. I never checked the php permissions but i added mkdir ($dir, 0744); to make sure php would have full permissions and it still does not recognize the files

Comment: You example shows that it can't even __see___ the files.... it doesn't care how files are created, whether by ghostscript or not (that's a complete red herring), and you're not trying to read the files in any way, just the content of the directory; so it's either permissions or looking in the wrong place

Comment: Looking in the right folder is easier to check using `echo getcwd();` to show what folder the script is actually executing in - something that a lot of people don't always know or understand

Comment: @MarkBaker I'll try what you suggested, But i just can't fathom why when reading one file with the syntax "jpgs/originals/myfile.png" it would find the file but when reading a file "jpgs/originals/ghost.png." it would move to a different directory

Comment: @MarkBaker, I just tried the `echo getcwd();` by doing this`$filename = "jpgs/originals/ghost.png";
echo getcwd();
$filename = "jpgs/originals/mine.png";
echo getcwd();` Both echos return the same path

Comment: Then it must be a case of file permissions then

Comment: @MarkBaker OH MY GOD dude, you won't believe what the problem was. Running the ghostscript parameter : `jpgs\originals\%3d.png` creates  files with 2 spaces in front of the digit. So calling the file 2.png doesn't work because it doesn't exist but if you call [space][space]2.png it works! And when windows copies the file it must erase the extra spaces or something. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**This is certainly a weird problem,** when running the ghostscript parameter :`jpgs\originals\%3d.png` it creates  files with 2 spaces in front of the digit. So calling the file 2.png doesn't work because it doesn't exist but if you call [space][space]2.png it works! And when windows copies the file it must erase the extra spaces or something.